# How do I feed a string into other app, as if written on a keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, macos

i want to now how i can write a String in a textfield in  another Application.
For example i run the programm, the programm waits for 5 seconds and i focus on a textfield in another Application for example Skype (by clicking it) and then the programm writes a string into the focused textfield.
I already know how to simulate single keystrokes with `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent`, but this doesn`t work really well with strings of 10-30 chars.
Thank you for your answers and soyrry for my really bad Grammar.

Comment: If Obj-C/iOS is designed along sensible lines then you can't.  Applications in a multitasking operating system each get their own memory space to run in and they can't access each other's state.  The user can copy to/paste from clipboard, but that's a user-initiated event.  What are you trying to do exactly?  What does the code that you've written with CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent look like?

Comment: He’s talking about OS X, not iOS. It’s possible to send events to other apps there, mainly to aid accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answers
i dont want to pass data i just want to create a virtual keyboard that writes a string into a textfield.